# The item provided was not valid

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have two tables Search and Criteria, I want to insert into Search table with following dictionary so I can save Search and Criteria at the same time on server like mentioned in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/08/23/complex-types-and-azure-mobile-services.aspx):

> {
>       favourite = 0;
>       id = "038754C5-8442-4726-B870-50B30D6C0FD9";
>       "ms_createdAt" = "460154444.053479";
>       "ms_updatedAt" = "460154444.053487";
>       searchcriteria =     {
>           id = "D7ADE004-92E7-4347-A6E6-DB66260F0364";
>           latitude = "41.08482";
>           location = "Akron, OH";
>           longitude = "-81.51561";
>           "ms_createdAt" = "460154444.055491";
>           "ms_updatedAt" = "460154444.055498";
>           radius = 10;
>           schoolLevels = "";
>           schoolRating = 5;
>           schoolTypes = "";
>       };
>       title = "";
>       userId = "Facebook:123123123123123"; }

Here's my client side code:

```
[self.searchTable insert:item completion:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error)
     {
         [self logErrorIfNotNil:error];
         completion(result);
     }];
```

I got the following error:

> Error Domain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain
>   Code=-1103 "The item provided was not valid." UserInfo=0x7ff093969400
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=The item provided was not valid.}

I created the dictionary with the following method:

```
- (NSDictionary*) toDictionaryWithTraversalHistory:(NSMutableSet*)traversalHistory {
    NSArray* attributes = [[[self entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
    NSArray* relationships = [[[self entity] relationshipsByName] allKeys];
    NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:
                                 [attributes count] + [relationships count] + 1];

    NSMutableSet *localTraversalHistory = nil;

    if (traversalHistory == nil) {
        localTraversalHistory = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[attributes count] + [relationships count] + 1];
    } else {
        localTraversalHistory = traversalHistory;
    }

    [localTraversalHistory addObject:self];

    //[dict setObject:[[self class] description] forKey:@"class"];

    for (NSString* attr in attributes) {
        if ([attr isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
            continue;
        }
        NSObject* value = [self valueForKey:attr];

        if (value != nil) {
            if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
                NSTimeInterval date = [(NSDate*)value timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
                NSString *dateAttr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", attr];
                [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:date] forKey:dateAttr];
            } else {
                [dict setObject:value forKey:attr];
            }
        }
    }

    for (NSString* relationship in relationships) {
        NSObject* value = [self valueForKey:relationship];

        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]) {
            // To-many relationship

            // The core data set holds a collection of managed objects
            NSSet* relatedObjects = (NSSet*) value;

            // Our set holds a collection of dictionaries
            NSMutableArray* dictSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[relatedObjects count]];

            for (NSManagedObject* relatedObject in relatedObjects) {
                if ([localTraversalHistory containsObject:relatedObject] == NO) {
                    [dictSet addObject:[relatedObject toDictionaryWithTraversalHistory:localTraversalHistory]];
                }
            }

            [dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:dictSet] forKey:relationship];
        }
        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSOrderedSet class]]) {
            // To-many relationship

            // The core data set holds an ordered collection of managed objects
            NSOrderedSet* relatedObjects = (NSOrderedSet*) value;

            // Our ordered set holds a collection of dictionaries
            NSMutableArray* dictSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[relatedObjects count]];

            for (NSManagedObject* relatedObject in relatedObjects) {
                if ([localTraversalHistory containsObject:relatedObject] == NO) {
                    [dictSet addObject:[relatedObject toDictionaryWithTraversalHistory:localTraversalHistory]];
                }
            }

            [dict setObject:[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:dictSet] forKey:relationship];
        }
        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]]) {
            // To-one relationship

            NSManagedObject* relatedObject = (NSManagedObject*) value;

            if ([localTraversalHistory containsObject:relatedObject] == NO) {
                // Call toDictionary on the referenced object and put the result back into our dictionary.
                [dict setObject:[relatedObject toDictionaryWithTraversalHistory:localTraversalHistory] forKey:relationship];
            }
        }
    }

    if (traversalHistory == nil) {
        [localTraversalHistory removeAllObjects];
    }

    return dict;
}

- (NSDictionary*) toDictionary {
    // Check to see there are any objects that should be skipped in the traversal.
    // This method can be optionally implemented by NSManagedObject subclasses.
    NSMutableSet *traversedObjects = nil;
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(serializationObjectsToSkip)]) {
        traversedObjects = [self performSelector:@selector(serializationObjectsToSkip)];
    }
    return [self toDictionaryWithTraversalHistory:traversedObjects];
}
```

Comment: Is this an insert into the local store via an MSSyncTable or direct to the server via MSTable?

Comment: @phillipv I want to insert directly into server via MSTable or API. I am getting error with both MSTable and API.

Comment: The 1103 error indicates it can't serialize the item, I tried making your object directly as is in ObjC and calling insert and it took it fine and sent to server so not sure what the issue.  Where are you getting item from?  (If item came from our sync table read call I'd expect the properties to have been converted back to __updatedAt, etc)

Comment: @phillipv I directly converted search object into dictionary and just passed it on.

Comment: @phillipv I have updated the question as to how I created the dictionary in the first place.

Comment: This is the function throwing: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/iOS/src/MSJSONSerializer.m#L48, I havent got a chance to see what your functions output looks like to see why it would complain.